# how to show info of a column in datatable at Primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I have a p:datatable. I want to show different info when the user navigate during different rows of datatable. For example, if the user navigate into row 1 at any column without clicking it by mouse, it will show a message Info 1 or if the user navigate into row2 without clicking it, it will show a message Info 2 . It can be a message of informative or next to row, any message.

Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use primefaces tooltip. Have a look at below link :

[PF-TOOLTIP](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/tooltip/tooltipOptions.xhtml)

Comment: If it solves your problem..please mark it as the answer of the question...